# List description displayed in webpart

Tags: web-part, jquery, data-view-web-part, custom

Is it possible to display the description of a library in SharePoint?  For example, I have a list of links that are specific.  I'm designing a webpart that displays the links, but I want the description from the list/library itself to appear on the page,.

FYI - I need to be able to do this without delving into C#/VB.Net programming

Let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: A Webpart without a DLL, that would be a "Client WebPart" right? So I'm guessing 2013 and SharePoint hosted app?

Comment: this is 2010, and a data query webpart.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. But if the description is a list property (not items), perhaps you could use client object model instead? (It is very easy, I can give an example answer if that is what you are looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list description of the code:

```
public String GetDescriptionList(SPList list)
{
    return list.Description;
}

public String GetDescriptionList(SPWeb web, String listName)
{
   return GetDescriptionList(web.Lists[listName]);
}
```

Comment: i want to do this outside of visual studio - preferably within SPD